# Why set subStatusCode to -1 in Web.config?

Tags: .net, web-config, http-status-codes

Apologies if this is obvious, but I have searched around and am unable to find an answer.

In a `.net Web.config` file, could anyone tell me what setting the `subStatusCode` to - 1 does?

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

My guess is that it means all the 'sub' codes, 404.1, 404.2.. etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[-1 is the default value for the `subStatusCode` in IIS](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors/error).

That said, you are removing the element here, so it's just restating the obvious (remove *all* prior entries for the `statusCode`).

In this case (with the `remove` element) it's not needed.